# Is my toothbrush plug compatible with UK bathroom socket?

Tags: uk, electronic-items, power

I have a toothbrush charger that is supposed to have a standard UK bathroom plug, but when I'm trying to plug it into the socket, it is very loose, and I'm not sure if it is charging as there is no indicator on the charger. See the images below. Is it the plug that is non-standard or is it the socket?

Note this is not a standard European plug - I have a EU extension cord so I checked. The span of the pins is too narrow. It is a BS4573 plug.

[image: socket]
[image: plug]

Comment: Looks more like a European plug than a UK plug (your plug, not the socket).

Comment: Chart: Which does your seem more like? https://www.europlugs.com/Wonpro_images/_home_page/Outlets_All_Types,w760.jpg

Comment: And do you *normally* plug it into the "shavers only" plug?

Comment: The plug is a standard British shaver plug and the socket looks like a multi-plug receptacle.  It could be that someone crammed something in the outlet that was too big and bent the contacts inside so they don't grip.  Or maybe they are just getting well used and lost some of their spring.

Comment: @Tom, would you like to write this as an answer?

Comment: @alkamid your wish in my command ... done deal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BS4573 plug is a standard British shaver plug and the socket looks like a multi-plug receptacle.

It could be that someone crammed something in the outlet that was too big and bent the contacts inside so they don't grip. Or maybe they are just getting well used and lost some of their spring.

You can try shining a flashlight into the socket to see if the contacts are visible or bent back.